# White marks in string printed in PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2016

I have PowerShell command that's executing the SQL Query and it is returning this query as XML.

```
$query = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select * from LS.dbo.live_Holdbacks FOR XML PATH('test');" -ServerInstance 'localhost')
$query | FORMAT-TABLE -Wrap
```

The problem is I have to print this result on the screen and then something strange happens. There are white marks in random places. You can see it marked on red. Word "Number" is literally split in the middle for no reason. What may cause it and how should I deal with it? [image]

Comment: Why are you using `Format-Table`? What does does `$query.XML_F52...` output?

Comment: SQL Statement returns XML (XML PATH). I want PowerShell to display output (prodeced xml) to the cmd as a plain text as it is. The only problem is that it produce line breaks.

Comment: Did you verify that your unformatted XML output (`$query` and/or `$query | Select-Object -Expand XML_F52E...`) does not have these breaks?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it looks exactly the same when printing by `$query | Select-Object -Expand XML_F52E...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I dealt with it. Script below returns whole XML without those white marks.

```
   $query = @(Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select top 100 * from LS.dbo.live_Holdbacks FOR XML PATH('test');" -MaxCharLength 100000 -ServerInstance 'localhost'  )

   $count = $query.Count
   $out_string = ''

   for($i=0; $i -lt $count; $i++){

    $r = $query[$i].ItemArray[0].Trim()

    $out_string += $r

   }

  $out_string
```